# Asp.net grid view

Tags: asp.net, edit, aspxgridview

I am nt able to edit the details in gridview.
When i click on Edit link(Command Field), row editing event is fired but when i click on update link , row editing event is fired again and update event is not getting fired at all.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: You may start by showing the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Hi Manoj, Darin is right, please post more info or contact the DevExpress support team at: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code:
May be you should try using debugger and check.
Here i have given an example for you.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        // Retrieve the row being edited.
        int index = GridView1.EditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        TextBox t2 = row.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
        string t3 = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        lblMsg.Text = "Updated record " + t1.Text + "," + t2.Text + "Value From Bound Field" + t3;
    }
```